# byte array convert to ascii string is garbled

Tags: java, string, byte, ascii

i have byte array,and i want to convert to `ascii` string.but i'm not sure whether it's ascii,
i'm not sure whether it's right format,i use

```
org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.newStringUsAscii (driveCodeByte);
```

but the converted string is garbled as the below picture,so what can i do to convert to correct format?

even i'm not sure it is ascii or maybe some other encode format.

[image]

Comment: What counts as "garbled"? We have no idea what the original data was, or what output you expect. It would really help if you'd give more context, with sample input data and expected output data.

Comment: i really don't know the output content,i just know the byte array should convert to ascii string,but now my convert is not correct because it is garbled

Comment: I strongly suspect it's *not* ASCII text then, and you shouldn't actually convert it to ASCII. If you don't *know* it was originally text, you shouldn't just assume that it is. You say you "don't know the output content" - surely you have some idea what the information is there for. If you don't, why are you using it at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a `byte[]` to `String` and convert the encoding, you don't need external frameworks.

- Use `String original = new String(myByteArray, myOriginalEncoding)` to get a `String` from your `byte[]` given the expected encoding.
- Then, initialize a new `String` again to convert to whichever encoding (ASCII here): `String converted = new String(original.getBytes(myOriginalEncoding), "Cp1252")`

**Note**

You **must** know the encoding for your original `String` to be interpreted with, i.e. `UTF-8`, `ISO Latin 1`, etc.

Comment: `Cpp1252` ... do you mean `Cp1252`?

Comment: @Tom oops! Fixed. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: but i don't know the encoding,and i try every encoding but it is still garbled

Comment: @user2245634 if you have tried to interpret the original `String` in  a number of common encodings with no luck, it might be that it was itself mis-encoded. In that case there isn't much you can do, save from looking where/how this `byte[]` is built in the first place...

Comment: yes,i suppose the byte[] maybe not correct.thanks

Comment: @user2245634 you're welcome. Pity it didn't help much.